# What are the parameters in PySCF's Selected Configuration Interaction code

Tags: electronic-structure, ab-initio-calculations, pyscf, configuration-interaction, full-configuration-interaction

Dear StackExchange Members,

I'm using the native PySCF implementation of selected configuration interaction (SCI). However, I can't seem to find any documentation detailing the algorithm or various user-defined parameters contained within.

I'm particularly interested in the parameters, `select_cutoff` and `ci_coeff_cutoff`. Based on the [PySCF documentation](https://pyscf.org/_modules/pyscf/fci/selected_ci.html), I had originally thought they were similar to the $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ parameters in heat-bath CI, although I'm now unsure of this. As many different flavours of SCI algorithms I would like some clarification on this.

If anyone has any experience in this or can point me in the correct direction, it would  be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! We hope to see much more of you in the future !!!